# Reload and scroll all buffers to the bottom

Tags: vim, logging

I have two log files open side-by-side and I want to be able to view them easily.
I can easily map

```
:bufdo e
```

to something to reload buffers, but i'm stuck on the scrolling part.

Is there a way to send `G` to the command?

Comment: Uhmm, maybe it would be better if you were to tell us what it is you're trying to do in the first place. From my understanding you want the buffers to "autorefresh" and to show the new entries at the bottom, right? That's the "bufdo e" and the "G" part. Have you thought about "autoread"?

Comment: Yeah, autoread does something similar to bufdo e part, but my question is more like - "What command scrolls buffer to the bottom"?

Comment: Are you perhaps looking for :execute "normal G"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you probably should use `:windo`

to scroll all your splitted window to the bottom you could do:

```
:windo normal! G
```

Comment: Yes, of course! You cannot scroll buffer, you only can scroll view of the buffer, which window is.